# Is there a difference between "cash paid" and "cash tendered"?

Tags: word-choice, differences

I notice that some receipts have the words "Cash Paid" while others have "Cash Tendered". Are there differences between them? Can they be used interchangeably? Are there situation(s) where one of them will be more suitable than the other?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The two phrases are often used interchangeably, in a conversational context. For casual usage, *cash paid* is more informal and more common than *cash tendered*. But there **is** a difference in meaning between the two phrases, in accounting, specifically for cashiering and bookkeeping.

#### A few background details

In bookkeeping there are **Accounts Receivable** (A/R) and **Accounts Payable** (A/P). Money owed to you accumulates in A/R. Bills and debt obligations owed to others is tallied under A/P.

### Scenario 1

*Cash tendered* is a sum of money given in payment. It may not be equal to the exact amount owed. Using cashiering as an example (which is part of a business's A/R), cash is presented as payment for a service or to settle an outstanding bill. That cash is **tendered**. If it is exactly equivalent to the amount of money owed, then *cash tendered* is **equal to** (the amount of) *cash paid*.

### Scenario 2

If the amount of *cash tendered* is **greater than** the amount owed, a credit balance is owed to the customer. The credit might be change, or it might be entered onto the books of the business as an A/P item due to that customer in the future. This is a case when *cash tendered* is **greater than** *cash paid*. Note that *cash tendered* minus *cash paid* equals change returned to the customer or the sum entered into the books as A/P.

### Scenario 3

If the amount of *cash tendered* is **less than** amount owed, the business ***might*** accept this money. If so, A/R would be reduced by  the amount of cash tendered. Often the terms of the transaction will not allow cash tendered to be less than the amount due though! Examples are restaurant bills and installment payments e.g. credit card monthly charges or a mortgage payment. If so, **none** of the cash tendered by the customer will be accepted by the business. This is a scenario where *cash tendered* is **greater than** zero while *cash paid* is **equal to** zero.

Comment: +1 Never thought that there is a difference as in the context for accounting. Fortunately, it can be used interchangeably in a conversational context.

Comment: Yes, it is *much* more straightforward in a conversation! But even if you aren't an accountant, it helps to be aware that small business software apps like Quickbooks will assign different meanings to tendered versus paid. I got all confused by that when I first used Quickbooks because I didn't realize there was a difference.